# Hexadecimal to decimal conversion with sprintf in C

Tags: c, hex, printf, decimal, ascii

I have

```
sprintf(ascii,"%X",number) // number = 63 is a decimal integer`
```

`char ascii[] = {51, 70, 0, 0, 0, .... }`  which displayed as "3F"

When I have

```
value = atoi(ascii);
```

It returns `value = 3`  not 63.

The thing that I want is hexadecimal conversion with sprintf, display it but then save the value inside the table as decimal to another variable.

How it can be done ?

Comment: `atoi` only knows about decimal numbers - use `strtol` with base 16 or `sscanf` with `%x`.

Comment: What about just doing `value = number;`?

Comment: Because, i change the content of the ascii array by incrementing or decrementing the values, after convert to decimal then save it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is atoi doesn't parse hex. You need a function that parses a hex digit. `sscanf(ascii, "%x", &i)` comes to mind...

Answer (score 4):

As pointed by others `atoi` doesnt parse hex. You can try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[] = "3F";
    int x;
    sscanf(s, "%x", &x);
    printf("%u\n", x);
}
```

**[IDEONE SAMPLE](https://ideone.com/uYnNOM)**

or you can use [strol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) like this:

```
printf("%u\n", strtol("3F", NULL, 16));
```

**[IDEONE SAMPLE](https://ideone.com/uYnNOM)**